# Computations using "Stover's spectral sequence"

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, spectral-sequences

In [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/004093839090022C) from 1990, Stover describes a specral sequence which converges to the higher homotopy groups of the homotopy colimit of a diagram $\underline{X}$ of topological spaces.

The second page terms $E^2_{p,*}$ are described as values of the $p^{th}$ derived functor of the colimit functor $\lim_p (\pi_*(\underline{X}))$ (where I use $\lim$ to mean the colimit functor) on the associated diagram of homotopy algebras $\pi_*(\underline{X})$. Here, for $p=0$ we take the normal colimit functor $\lim (\pi_*(\underline{X}))$.

This derived functor is defined as $\pi_p({\lim{F_*}})$ - that is, the $p^{th}$ homotopy group of the simplicial $\Pi$-algebra $\lim{F_*}$, where $F_*$ is a free simplicial resolution of the diagram $\pi_*(\underline{X})$.

In order to take the above $p^{th}$ homotopy group, I need to know the face and degeneracy maps in the simplicial object $\lim F_*$.

How are the face and degeneracy maps for $\lim F_*$ defined here?

Comment: I’d consider asking this on MO.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/350866/11260